# Problem referring to a third model in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have three models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    document = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20) 

class Address(models.Model):
    person= models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='person_address', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=9)

class StatusPerson(models.Model):
    person = models.OneToOneField(Person, related_name='person_status', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sms_status = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    activation_status = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
```

I want to know the the status of the person from the adress class. 
I've try to:

```
def user_sms_status(self):
    return self.person.StatusPerson.sms_status
```

And I receive the error:
'Person' object has no attribute 'StatusPerson'

Can Anyone help me to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the class name `StatusPerson`, you should use what you've declared in `related_name='person_status'`.

So, your function should be something like this:

```
  def user_sms_status(self):
    return self.person.person_status.sms_status
```

You can [read more about it here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).